# I'm unable to make my html/css/bootstrap file responsive and be able to fit any screen's resolution

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, web, responsive, bootstrap-5

i'm new to web developement and i would like to know how i can make my file elements responsive and be able to fit any screen's size or resolution. Help is much appreciated! Here's my code :

```
`\<!DOCTYPE html\>
\<html lang="en"\>

\<head\>
\<meta charset="utf-8"\>
\<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no"\>
\<title\>Untitled\</title\>
\<!-- CSS only --\>
\<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous"\>
\</head\>

\<body style="background: #fadc74;"\>

    <style>

.btn-solo {
background-color: #52D2B3;
background-image: src=url('C:/Users/BIS PLUS/Desktop/Maquette Traveler to CHINGUIT/img/no-alarm.png');
/\* background-position: -9px -7px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 59px 46px;
padding-left: 41px;
font-weight: 550;
\*/
max-width: 40%;
max-height: 40%;

}

.btn-multi {
background-color: #D8DB36;
font-weight: 550;
max-width: 40%;
}

.btn-defi {
background-color: #FFCDCD;
font-weight: 550;
max-width: 40%;

}

.btn-classement {
background-color: #FF9211;
font-weight: 550;

max-width: 40%;

}

    </style>  
    
    <div class="container mx-auto d-block">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <img src="/img/Logo.png" style="position: absolute;width: 370px;height: 357px;top: 164px;">
    <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
    <button class="btn btn-solo shadow w-30 p-2 mb-2 " type="button" style="position: absolute;width: 500px;height: 56.6px; top: 752px;  border-radius: 20px; ">SOLO LIBRE</button>
    <button class="btn btn-multi shadow w-30 p-2 mb-2 " type="button" style="position: absolute;width: 500px;height: 56.6px;top: 868.74px; border-radius: 20px">MULTIJOUEURS</button>
    <button class="btn btn-defi shadow w-30 p-2 mb-2 " type="button" style="position: absolute;width: 500px;height: 56.6px;top: 1000.49px; border-radius: 20px">DÉFI CONTRE LA MONTRE</button>
    <button class="btn btn-classement shadow w-30 p-2 mb-2 " type="button" style="position: absolute;width: 500px;height: 56.6px;top: 1109px; border-radius: 20px">CLASSEMENT DES JOUEUERS</button>

\</div\>
\</div\>
\</div\>  
\</div\>
\</div\>

       <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->

\<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"\>\</script\>
\</body\>

\</html\>`
```

I tried fitting the image and the buttons in one page and be able to fit them regardless of any screen's resolution but since i'm new to bootstrap i don't know how.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your site is responsive.
I was able to clean up some of your code so it renders a bit better, and things work much better now.

I noticed a lot of your closing tags had 2 slashes `</div/>` which could be a reason why you weren't seeing any responsiveness before.

Hope this helps somewhat! If you need any help with Bootstrap, feel free to send me a msg!

```css
.btn-solo {
  background-color: #52D2B3;
  background-image: src=url('C:/Users/BIS PLUS/Desktop/Maquette Traveler to CHINGUIT/img/no-alarm.png');
  font-weight: 550;
  max-width: 40%;
  max-height: 40%;
}

.btn-multi {
  background-color: #D8DB36;
  font-weight: 550;
  max-width: 40%;
}

.btn-defi {
  background-color: #FFCDCD;
  font-weight: 550;
  max-width: 40%;

}

.btn-classement {
  background-color: #FF9211;
  font-weight: 550;
  max-width: 40%;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html\>
<html lang="en">

 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <title>Untitled</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

  <body style="background: #fadc74;">

    <div class="container mx-auto d-block">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
          <img src="/img/Logo.png" style="position: absolute;width: 370px;height: 357px;top: 164px;">
          <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">

            <button class="btn btn-solo shadow w-30 p-2 mb-2 " type="button" style="position: absolute;width: 500px;height: 56.6px; top: 752px;  border-radius: 20px; ">SOLO LIBRE</button>

            <button class="btn btn-multi shadow w-30 p-2 mb-2 " type="button" style="position: absolute;width: 500px;height: 56.6px;top: 868.74px; border-radius: 20px">MULTIJOUEURS</button>

            <button class="btn btn-defi shadow w-30 p-2 mb-2 " type="button" style="position: absolute;width: 500px;height: 56.6px;top: 1000.49px; border-radius: 20px">DÉFI CONTRE LA MONTRE</button>

            <button class="btn btn-classement shadow w-30 p-2 mb-2 " type="button" style="position: absolute;width: 500px;height: 56.6px;top: 1109px; border-radius: 20px">CLASSEMENT DES JOUEUERS</button>

            </div>
          
        </div>
        
      </div>
      
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous" \>
      </script>
            </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and the help! Is it possible though to scale the elements when it comes the screen's resolution so they could all fit without having to scroll up or down?

Comment: @DahSidiAbdallah, yes, read about breakpoints here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/breakpoints/#core-concepts